# Convert VARIANTARG to QString

Tags: c++, qt, com, ole

I'm use [QAxBase::signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxbase.html#signal) to connect COM events.

QAxBase::signal has arguments:

```
signal(const QString &name, int argc, void *argv)
```

void *argv converted to [VARIANTARG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms221627(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
VARIANTARG *params = (VARIANTARG*)argv;
// *params[2] - it's QString
```

How to convert VARIANTARG to QString?

**UPD:**

VARIANTARG structure:

```
long error, long code, BSTR message
```

Comment: Do you know what type the variant union represents? If not, I'd say this question is far too broad.

Comment: Never used Qt, but I'd first convert the Variant to a BSTR using windows VariantChangeType() API.  After that, there has to be a simple way to go from a BSTR to a QString.